# Return "text/plain" With Slim 3

Tags: slim-3

I'm writing a route which should return a "text/plain" content type (only for this route).

`$response->withHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain')->write("HELLO");`

Am I doing it wrong? I keep on getting "text/html".

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you do not return or re-assign the returned `Response` from the `withHeader`-method, because the default content type is `text/plain`.

The `Response`-object is immutable therefore only return a changed object on the `withX`-methods.

The solution is to return the response

```
$app->get('/foo', function($request, $response) {
    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')->write('HELLO');
});
```